# How do you setup Ninject with WCF Services while maintaining Domain Driven Design architecture?

Tags: c#, wcf, dependency-injection, domain-driven-design, ninject

I am trying to achieve a proof of concept where I write a module (let's say Forum for the purpose of this discussion) that follows Domain Driven Design guidelines and will have a pluggable repository and the entire module will be pluggable either locally in a web server (local hosted dll) or through WCF services.

Following Domain Driven Design guidelines, I would have a set of business objects that would be written like this:

```
    public class Forum
    {
        readonly IRepository _forumRepository;
        public Forum(IRepository forumRepository)
        {
            _forumRepository = forumRepository;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public void Save()
        {
            _forumRepository.SaveForum(this);
        }
    }
```

Let's say the web application needs to create a new forum.

This is all well and good if the module is hosted locally via a dll file.  The web application code would simply use Ninject (or whatever DI) to instantiate the business object and call the Save method.

However, what if the implementers wanted to introduce a service layer in between?  Let's say they want to introduce a WCF Services layer in between the application and the database layer because they want the physical architecture to be Web Server -> App Server -> DB Server.  Obviously, the Forum module dll would be hosted by both the web server and the app server.  However, the module is no longer usable.

If the web server instantiates the object with the repository injection and passes it across the WCF Service layer, the _forumRepository field will get lost even if I allow for my business objects to be serialized.

The implementor should be able to make the application server choose the repository anyway.  So, with this requirement, how would the implementor inject the repository on the application server side after receiving the already instantiated object from the web server?  Is there a way to tell WCF Services to inject the repository when it instantiates the object during the deserialization process?

I read the article, *[How to use Dependency Injection (Ninject) with WCF Services](http://www.aaronstannard.com/post/2011/08/16/dependency-injection-ninject-wcf-service.aspx)*, and reviewed the example solution, but this only demonstrates how to inject the repository directly into the service.  It doesn't appear to solve the problem I am discussing here.

Here is an example of how I foresee the code to be if written correctly.  As I stated before, the main problem here is that I don't know how I can inject the repository into the domain object on the services side.

Application Code (Web App or Windows App):

```
Forum newForum = new Forum();
//Set some properties on newForum.        
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();  //Instantiate ninject kernel.
//Yes, I know using the using statement means that IService needs to derive from IDisposable.  A local service would just have an empty implementation for IDisposable since there would be nothing to clean up and this would allow different service architectures to be plugged into the application.
using (IForumService forumService = kernel.Get<IForumService>())  //Get concrete implementation bound to IForumService via ninject.
{
    //Send forum to service layer for local OR WCF processing (on an app server)
    forumService.SaveForum(newForum);
}
```

Services Code (This is the problem):

```
public class WCFForumService : IForumService
{
    public void SaveForum(Forum forum)
    {
        //PROBLEM SCENARIO:  How do I now inject the repository I want to use since I already have an instance of forum?  
        //Can I make WCF inject the repository when it is deserializing the forum object before passing it into this method?
        forum.Save();
    }
}
```

I would prefer to not force implementers of my forum module into creating DTOs for every domain object if at all possible.  This violates the DRY principle.  It would be great if I could create my domain objects so they are generic and/or extensible enough to be used as the DTOs themselves with very little effort.  This way, I can put business rule validation on the domain objects using Data Annotations and the implementer can use these objects in a Web Forms, MVC3, or Silverlight project without having to re-work all of the validation manually.

**EDIT:** THE ABOVE IS ENTIRELY THE WRONG APPROACH.  EDITING TO DEMONSTRATE A MORE VALID APPROACH.

```
public class Forum
{
    public Forum(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IForumRepository : IRepository<Forum>
{
    void Add(Forum forum);
    Forum this[object id] { get; set; }
}

//Client Code (Called from the WCF service hosting the domain)
public class WCFAppService
{
    public void SaveForum(ForumDTO forumInfo)
    {
        IKernel kernel = StandardKernel();
        IForumRepository repository = kernel.Get<IForumRepository>();
        Forum forum = repository[forumInfo.ID];
        if (forum != null)
        {
            repository[forumInfo.ID] = forumInfo.CopyTo(forum); //Save the Forum to the db.
        }
        else
        {
            repository.Add(ForumFactory.CreateFrom(forumInfo)); //Insert the Forum into the db.
        }
    }
}
```

Much of the problem that I had when attempting this prototype was that I was focusing too much on the infrastructure concerns (ie. DI, server architecture, etc) while trying to learn DDD in the process.  What I have learned about DDD brings me to the conclusion that, when attempting to figure out how to structure a DDD solution, forget about architecture and technology until you have a good grip on what DDD will do for you.  I make this note because in my actual DDD project that I am currently working on, DI seems like an unnecessary complication.  That's how simple DDD can make your code.

Comment: The whole point of adding a service layer is to separate concerns. Skiping layers as you want to do it is bad practice. You do not want to care about such low level things like saving to the database in you application/presentation layer anymore. This is the job of the service/business layer. This means the repository has nothing to do in the application. Do what Mike succests starting from the third paragraph.

Comment: I'm not trying to skip layers.  If the implementer wants to create the architecture I suggested Web Server -> App Server -> DB Server, then the web server would be responsible for calling the app server (either via direct reference or injection, that's up to the implementer) and the app server would be responsible for injecting the repository.  I added some notes to my question for clarification over what I'm wanting to know.

Comment: Yes you are skipping. I added an answer because a comment would get too long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By passing your repositories to the web server you are skipping layers. Nothing prevents you from calling save there or manipulate data in a way that is not allowed by your business rules. Furthermore, you don't want to care about database details on the web server. This is the responsibility of the app server.

There should be a completely different interface between app and db server as between app and web server. The interface of the app server should consist of the actions you want to perform on your web server.

Lets say you have a bank accout system. And want to perform a transaction between two accouts. In this case in your solution you would send the two involved accouts to the webserver and it decreases the balance of the first account by the transfered amount and increases the second one by the same amount. Then it sends the accounts back to the appserver for saving.

But this is wrong. What's correct is to provide a service on the app server that provides a transaction method that takes the involved account numbers and the amount to be transfered and the complete operation is done on the app server.

In your example you should provide a method `ChangeForumName(int forumId, string newName)`. Here you can now ensure the rules that the name must fulfill. E.g. not empty.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  You were right about how I was taking entirely the wrong approach.

Answer (score 4):

If you really really wanted to have the services in the domain object after sending it over the wire, then have your services as properties of your objects and in the "Get" method use some sort of CommonServiceLocator pattern to get the services at the other side. See here for more info http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/  (i.e. rather than WCF injecting the services, the object calls out to CommonServiceLocator to get instances of the services it requires).

Another approach might be to write a custom wcf behaviour that injected the services.  Check out this article for more details - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163302.aspx

However, you should think more closely about your architecture and what you want to achieve.  If you wanted to have  Web Server->App Server-->Db Server then really you should not be sending your object to your app server so that the app server can inject services and then call a "save" method on your object.  A cleaner design would be to have an app server (wcf in this case) that has a service with a save method that takes your "Forum" object as a parameter.  That service would then have the repository injected into it as per the article you referenced.

As you know, when using WCF you are really only sending serialized data across the wire and not actual objects.  The objects are reconstructed on the other side.  Lots of architectures use Data Transfer Objects for their WCF calls and then hydrate their domain models with these DTOs (although you can just use your domain objects for this remember that you are just sending the data).

This article has a good discussion on these topics http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236638.aspx (althoght your question wasn't about DTOs the principle applies to domain objects as well, and may give you some food for thought around how you are putting the pieces together).  Its also worth looking at how others are doing similar things.  There are some great sample apps around e.g. http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2009/04/12/a-layered-aspnet-mvc-application-part-i/  (you need to read the whole series as he doesn't talk about wcf in the first 2 parts)

Comment: +1 For the third and following paragraphs. Though, you should remove the first two. This shouldn't be done.

Comment: Yeah, the first paragraph doesn't seem like a good separation of concerns to me, violating the Domain Driven Design I am trying to follow.  Also, I realize that many people believe that DDD isn't practical, but that's why I'm writing this proof of concept.  

I will check out the links you sent, but I didn't think I asked the question well enough so I went ahead and added some more information for clarification.

Comment: Hi Aaron....I had a look at your clarification and I think you are still on the wrong track.  You should remove the "save" method entirely from your domain object.  Once you forget about getting the repository interface into your domain object things should become clearer for you.  My original answer still stands as it does answer the question asked (i.e. how to get wcf to inject services into your domain objects), but I think you need to rethink things.  DTOs are by no means required and you can achieve the same effect annotated domain objects (DataContract, DataMember).

Comment: Also, you should look up "Persistence Ignorance" in relation to domain objects.  Basically it says the domain object should not have to worry about how it is persisted (even if that is just an interface).  This will facilitate domain objects that are purely concerned with the function of that object and not with related infrastructre concerns such as persistance.  Check out anything by Jimmy Neilsson or have a quick scan of this article - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx

Comment: There are two schools of thought on whether having a "save" method on your object breaks DDD guidelines.  If you are sending your objects over the wire then I would argue that you shouldn't have a save method on them.  The Unit of Work article explains that a bit further under the heading Persistence Ignorance, which basically says your object should know need to know nothing about persistence and that a service (repository pattern) should be used to save your object.  In your implmentation if your UI layer wants to have an instance of an object and just call "save" on it then....

Comment: ...that save method sends the object to WCF service layer.  In the service you should have a repostory object that takes your object and saves it (not by calling "save" on your object in the WCF layer, but by just taking an instance of that object...looking at your code above it looks like you are setup for that already).  This article might explain this a little better than I am - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/aspnetmvc_bugtracker_v4.aspx .  If you want to have a multi tiered app then you are going to have to sacrifice some simplicity on your objects by using services.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4619/discussion-between-mike-hanrahan-and-aaron-hawkins)

Comment: Mike, I see now that I was on the wrong track as you suggested and have deleted my bogus comments as a result.  I agree that the UI layer should just pass the info to the WCF service which, in turn, should then instantiate the repository, build the domain object, and save it and I have updated my question to reflect this.  However, I do not agree with allowing domain objects to be serializable.  In my current view, serialization is an infrastructure concern.  A while after I asked this question, I came across Onion architecture and learned a great deal more about how to make it simpler.